# Angular8: Only Allow item to be deleted within 30 minutes of creation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, http-delete

I have an NGX table of certifications. The user is able to create new certifications which are added to the table. Each certification has a delete button to remove the certification from the table.

I want the delete button to only be available within 30 minutes after user has created a new certification.

I'm not sure how to get this done and I'm not sure what code snippets I need to share.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the delay operator of a piped observable based on creation date of the certification + 30 minutes

[http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-delay](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-delay)

If you have a ngrx state for example with an action + effect

Also maybe a template function on the remove button can do the job :

```
<button [disabled]="!canRemoveCertification(certification.createdAt)">remove</button>
```

```
canRemoveCertification(certificationCreation: Date){
 // compare createdDate + 30m to now date and return boolean
}
```